# Rabbitmq wait after processing message

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have following rabbit listener:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RabbitListener(queues = "${spring.rabbitmq.template.default-receive-queue}")
public class RabbitmqListener {
    private final Processor processor;

    @RabbitHandler(isDefault = true)
    public void receiveMessage(List<String> someData) {
        log.info("Received {} some data", someData.size());
        processor.process(someData);
        //should wait for 15 minutes here
    }
}
```

I need to configure listener to wait for 15 minutes after it processed one message before receiving next one. Not necessary to wait inside this method. All i need is NOT to receive any messages after processing one. It could be done by `Thread.sleep(15000)`, but i'm not sure that it's  the best way to achieve this. Is there any rabbitmq configuration for this kind of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.sleep(15000)` will wait for 15 seconds, not 15 minutes.

It's probably not a good idea to sleep for 15 minutes; if you only need to sleep for 15 seconds, a sleep is probably ok (but you do risk a redelivery if the server crashes while you are are sleeping).

You might want to consider using `RabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert()` instead for this use case, rather than using a message-driven architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if i would use `RabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert()`, i would still need to implement logic with executing this method and sleeping after it finished.

Comment: Right, but "pulling" messages from rabbit when you are ready for the next one is better than a message-driven architecture and artificially suspending the deliveries. Sleeping after pulling leaves nothing in a "pending" state.